# Is Object.create(null) different from {} while defining __proto__ as null?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

There seems to be a common approach to creating bare objects in javascript which is to use

`Object.create(null)`

to create an object without any pre-existing attributes. Is this any different from doing

```
var obj = {}
obj.__proto__ = null
```

or are they functionally identical? If the purpose of doing this is to use an object as a hashmap, would there be any change in performance or functionality between the two if **proto** was set to null after adding key-value pairs?

Comment: Whoops, tried searching and somehow that didn't turn up. I think that answers my question. My apologies.

Comment: No worries, it took me several searches to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they do basically the same.

> would there be any change in performance?

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) concludes on `obj.__proto__`:

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in `obj.__proto__ = ...` statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered.

So you should definetly use `Object.create(null)` ...